# Get current branch and commit number with https://github.com/clj-jgit/clj-jgit

Tags: git, clojure

How to get current branch and commit number with https://github.com/clj-jgit/clj-jgit?
I am trying

```
(def my-repo (load-repo "."))
(:id (first (git-log my-repo :max-count 1)))
```

but I don't know how to get string of underlying object.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about "something is not ok".  Please also add the errors you get or how the result is not what you expect.

Comment: @cfrick  of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using `(:id (first (git-log my-repo :max-count 1)))` will return the instance of the [RevCommit](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevCommit.html) class which inherits class [AnyObjectId](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/AnyObjectId.html) having method .getName() which will return the hash of the git commit.

```clj
;; for getting the hash
(.getName (:id (first (git-log my-repo :max-count 1))))
```

Now, for getting the current branch name, there is another function **git-branch-current** in the ns [clj-jgit.porcelain](https://github.com/clj-jgit/clj-jgit/blob/master/src/clj_jgit/porcelain.clj) namespace:

```clj
;; for getting the current branch name
(git-branch-current my-repo)
```